# How to add website name variable in wp shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a shortcode in wordpress.

Everything will be pulled dynamically (even website name), so the user doesn't need to change anything and the end result should be "Copyright 2015 Website title". I used the following code, but I'm getting a syntax error:

```
 function copyright_shortcode($atts){
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'company' => '<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>' 


    ),$atts,'copyright'));

$text='&copy;<span class="small"> Copyright '.date('Y') . $company.'</span>';


return $text;
}
add_shortcode('copyright','copyright_shortcode');
```

Syntax error is appearing in a row:

```
'company' => '<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us more information about the error you get?

Comment: The syntax highlighting might reveal the problem... You are trying to put PHP in a string. Instead of `'<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>'`, use `get_bloginfo('name')`

Comment: @LajosArpad I'm getting the error in the row `'company' => '<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're seeing is because you're using opening PHP tags when you're already inside a PHP statement.

```
'company' => '<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>'
```

Also the function `bloginfo()` will echo the value; you need to use a function that returns the value instead.

```
'company' => get_bloginfo( 'name' ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of

```
'company' => '<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>'
```

you intend to use

```
'company' => bloginfo('name')
```

Comment: nope, syntax error appears again, any other suggestions?

Comment: A semi colon remained. Can you try it again?

Comment: Nathan's solution did the trick, thanks for the time :)